# Partition a singly linked list using Java - follow-up

Tags: java, beginner, linked-list

This is a follow up to my last question:
[Partition a singly linked list using Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142194/partition-a-singly-linked-list-using-java)

Based on the feedback I received there, I changed the following about the code:

1. Added a `LinkedList` class.
2. Removed some variables from the `partition` method.
3. Changed the partition algorithm so that the output of the lower and upper partitions maintain their input order.  In particular one of the unit tests checks if calling partition on the same linked list twice leaves the list unchanged from the result of the first call.
4. Changed the unit tests to be less fragile by checking for correct output according to spec rather than hard-coding a single partition into the test.

I would appreciate any feedback on the updated code.

**LinkedList.java**

```
package practice_cracking_code_interview;

public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    public LinkedList(){}

    public Node getHead(){
        return this.head;
    }

    public void setTail(Node tail){
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    public Node getTail(){
        return this.tail;
    }

    public String stringify(){
        String listAsString = "Null";
        Node current = this.head;
        while(current != null){
            listAsString = listAsString + " -> " + current.data;
            current = current.next;
        }
        listAsString = listAsString + " -> " + "Null";
        return listAsString;
    }

    void appendToTail(Node n){
        if (n == null){
            return;
        }
        if(this.head == null){
            this.head = n;
            this.tail = n;
        }
        else{
            this.tail.next = n;
            this.tail = n;
        }
    }

    void partition(int p){
        LinkedList lowerList = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList upperList = new LinkedList();

        Node current = this.head;

        while(current != null){
            Node nextNode = current.next;
            if(current.data < p){
                lowerList.appendToTail(current);
                lowerList.getTail().next = null;
            }
            else{
                upperList.appendToTail(current);
                upperList.getTail().next = null;
            }
            current = nextNode;
        }

            lowerList.appendToTail(upperList.getHead());
            upperList.setTail(null);
            this.head = lowerList.getHead();
        }
    }
```

**Node.java**

```
package practice_cracking_code_interview;

public class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node(int d){
        data = d;
    }
}
```

**TestNode.java**

```
package practice_cracking_code_interview;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestNode extends TestCase {

    public void testAppendToTail(){
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        Node head = new Node(10);
        myList.appendToTail(head);
        assertEquals(head.data, 10);
    }

    public void testPartitionOne(){
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        Node head = new Node(3);
        myList.appendToTail(head);
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(5));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(8));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(5));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(10));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(2));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(1));
        myList.partition(5);
        Node current = myList.getHead();
        String messageInCaseOfFail;
        int i = 0;
        while(current != null){
            if(i < 3){
                assertTrue(current.data < 5);
                i++;
            }
            else if(i >=3 && i < 7)
            {
                messageInCaseOfFail = "i is: " + i + "and current node's value is " + current.data; 
                assertTrue(messageInCaseOfFail, current.data >= 5);
                i++;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        assertEquals(i, 7);
    }

    public void testPartitionTwo(){
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        Node head = new Node(3);
        myList.appendToTail(head);
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(5));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(8));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(5));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(10));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(2));
        myList.appendToTail(new Node(1));
        myList.partition(11);
        int[] partitionedList = new int[7];

        Node current = myList.getHead();
        int i = 0;
        while(current != null){
                assertTrue(current.data < 11);
                partitionedList[i] = current.data;
                i++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        assertEquals(i, 7);

        myList.partition(11);
        current = myList.getHead();
        i = 0;
        while(current != null){
            assertEquals(current.data, partitionedList[i]);
            i++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        assertEquals(i, 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Interface**

  Don't throw away results of your computation.

  `partition` partitions the list all right, and in the course of partitioning it necessarily computes a partition point. This is an extremely important piece of information (think `quicksort`). Return it. The caller will truly appreciate.

  ```
  node partition(int p) {
      ....
      return upperList.head;
  }
  ```
- **`appendToTail`**

  `tail` is set to `n` no matter what. Factor that out:

  ```
      if (this.head == null) {
          this.head = n;
      } else {
          this.tail.next = n;
      }
      this.tail = n;
  ```

  It is actually a good place to assert an invariant:

  ```
      if (this.head == null) {
          assert(this.tail == null);
          this.head = n;
      } else {
          assert(this.tail != null);
          this.tail.next = n;
      }
      this.tail = n;
  ```
- **`setTail`**

  is truly strange. I cannot imagine a legitimate use for such method. I can only see it breaking the list integrity.
- **`this`**

  Do you really need to use `this.` all over the place?

Comment: Is "upperList.getTail().next = null;" ok?

Comment: @newToProgramming Missed that. No I don't think so. Fails when `getTail` is `null`.  I suppose you should set `n.next = null` in `appendToTail`. I will double check and update my answer.